# C#: Reading a variable structured CSV file into a datatable with a row counter

Tags: c#, csv, datatable, streamreader

I am trying to develop a tool that will take a CSV file and import it into a datatable with the first column in the datatable being a row counter.

The CSV files are from different customers and so have different structures. Some have a header line; some have several header lines; some have no header line. They have also have varying columns.

So far, I have the code below.

```
    public void Import_CSV()
    {
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv";
        bool? result = dialog.ShowDialog();

        if (result ?? false)
        {
            string[] headers;

            string CSVFilePathName = dialog.FileName;

            string delimSelect = cboDelimiter.Items.GetItemAt(cboDelimiter.SelectedIndex).ToString();

            //  If user hasn't selected a delimiter, assume comma
            if (delimSelect == "")
            {
                delimSelect = ",";
            }

            string[] delimiterType = new string[] {cboDelimiter.Items.GetItemAt(cboDelimiter.SelectedIndex).ToString()};

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            //  Read first line of file to get number of fields and create columns and column numbers in data table
            using (StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader(CSVFilePathName))
            {
                headers = sr1.ReadLine().Split(delimiterType, StringSplitOptions.None);

                //dt.Columns.Add("ROW", typeof(int));
                //dt.Columns["ROW"].AutoIncrement = true;
                //dt.Columns["ROW"].AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
                //dt.Columns["ROW"].AutoIncrementStep = 1; 

                int colCount = 1;

                foreach (string header in headers)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add("C" + colCount.ToString());
                    colCount++;
                }
            }

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(CSVFilePathName))
            {
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string[] rows = sr.ReadLine().Split(delimiterType, StringSplitOptions.None);

                     DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

                    for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
                    {

                            dr[i] = rows[i];
                    }

                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
            }

            dtGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

            txtColCount.Text = dtGrid.Columns.Count.ToString();
            txtRowCount.Text = dtGrid.Items.Count.ToString();
        }
    }
```

This works, in as much as it creates column headers (C1, C2....according to how many there are in the csv file) and then the rows are written in, but I want to add a column at the far left with a row number as the rows are added. In the code, you can see I've got a section commented out that creates an auto-number column, but I'm totally stuck on how the rows are written into the datatable. If I uncomment that section, I get errors as the first column in the csv file tries to write into an int field. I know you can specify which field in each row can go in which column, but that won't help here as the columns are unknown at this point. I just need it to be able to read ANY file in, regardless of the structure, but with the row counter.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write in your question, that uncommenting the code that adds the first column leads to errors. This is because of your loop: it starts at 0, but the 0-th column is the one you have added manually. So you need just to skip it in your loop, starting at 1. However, the source array has to be processed from the 0-th element.

So the solution is:

First, uncomment the row adding code.

Then, in your loop, introduce an offset to leave the first column untouched:

```
for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
{
    dr[i + 1] = rows[i];
}
```

Comment: This could do with a bit more explanation, but it is the correct answer.

Comment: Hey Dymanoid, thanks for the input! And the answer! So simple in the end. Thanks again.